# Gradle's processResources expands '\n'

Tags: gradle

I want to expand a placeholder string in a resource file during my gradle build. I do this using:

```
processResources {
    expand(placeHolder: value)
}
```

When I run the `processResources` task the placeholder gets expanded correctly (so far so good).

Unfortunately gradle also replaces any `\n` strings with *acutal* newlines. My files contain these strings, and I don't want them to be replaced. Is it possible to disable this behavior?